# Best way to compile subdirectories into libraries with automake?

Tags: c++, autotools, automake, libtool

I have the following files

```
├── configure.ac
├── main.cpp
├── Makefile.am
└── procs
    ├── Makefile.am
    ├── proc1
    │   └── subprocs
    │       ├── subprocA
    │       │   ├── ProcA_SubprocA.cc
    │       │   └── ProcA_SubprocA.h
    │       └── subprocB
    │           ├── ProcA_SubprocB.cc
    │           └── ProcA_SubprocB.h
    ├── proc2
    │   └── subprocs
    │       ├── subprocA
    │       │   ├── ProcB_SubprocA.cc
    │       │   └── ProcB_SubprocA.h
    │       └── subprocB
    │           ├── ProcB_SubprocB.cc
    │           └── ProcB_SubprocB.h
    └── Subprocs.h
```

My goal is to create a library from everything in *procs* so it can be used in **main.cpp** which could look something like this:

## main.cpp

```
#include "Subprocs.h"

int main(){

    ProcA_SubprocA * p = new ProcA_SubprocA();
    p->use();
    delete p;

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to have all the includes of the subprocs in **Subprocs.h**, so it can be used as some kind of interface:

## Subprocs.h

```
#include "ProcA_SubprocA.h"
#include "ProcA_SubprocB.h"
#include "ProcB_SubprocA.h"
#include "ProcB_SubprocB.h"
```

My **configure.ac** looks like this:

## configure.ac

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([main], [0.1])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign subdir-objects])

#AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4]) 
#LT_INIT

AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_RANLIB

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile procs/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

and my **Makefile.am's** like this

## Makefile.am

```
SUBDIRS = procs

AM_CPPFLAGS = -Iprocs

bin_PROGRAMS = main
main_SOURCES = main.cpp
#added:
main_LDADD = procs/libprocs.a

#ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
```

## procs/Makefile.am

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -Iproc1/subprocs/subprocA -Iproc1/subprocs/subprocB \
              -Iproc2/subprocs/subprocA -Iproc2/subprocs/subprocB

#lib_LIBRARIES = libprocs.la
noinst_LIBRARIES = libprocs.a
libprocs_a_SOURCES = Subprocs.h \
                      proc1/subprocs/subprocA/ProcA_SubprocA.cc proc1/subprocs/subprocA/ProcA_SubprocA.h \
                      proc1/subprocs/subprocB/ProcA_SubprocB.cc proc1/subprocs/subprocB/ProcA_SubprocB.h \
                      proc2/subprocs/subprocA/ProcB_SubprocA.cc proc2/subprocs/subprocA/ProcB_SubprocA.h \
                      proc2/subprocs/subprocB/ProcB_SubprocB.cc proc2/subprocs/subprocB/ProcB_SubprocB.h
```

When I type

```
#libtoolize && autoreconf -i -f && ./configure && make
autoreconf -i -f && ./configure && make
```

I get a file called **libprocs.la** in *procs* but I don't get a binary. I am also fairly certain that my Makefiles are wrong since I can't even compile **main.cpp** by hand.

Is it at all possible to do what I want here? Or am I overthinking this and I don't even need a library in the first place? The important part for me is that **main.cpp** only includes **Subprocs.h** which then contains all includes of the subprocs.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `libtoolize` modifies your `Makefile.am` and `configure.ac` files, which is why you must `autoreconf` afterwards.  If that's the way you intend to go (and it's by no means wrong) then the `libtoolize` and `autoreconf` should be done *once*, not as part of every build.  Moreover, in that case it would be the post-`libtoolize` files that would be relevant to this question (it looks like that may indeed be what you presented, but please clarify).

Comment: Is the library intended *only* for the program you are building, or is it your intention to provide it for other programs, too?  Is it important for it to be a *shared* library?  Inasmuch as you do not appear to be installing the library's headers, I'm supposing that the library is for the one program only, and therefore that it does not need to be a shared library or even installed as a standalone library in its own right.  Please confirm.

Comment: The library is only intended for this program. I am trying to setup a structure here that would enable me to add new procs (proc3, proc4, ...) later with minimal effort and if possible no changes to anything above the **procs** directory.

Comment: I think you're going to a lot of work for negligible benefit.  The structure you're setting up seems to be harder to maintain overall, and I don't see how it has any advantage over a flat structure for adding new procs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous oddities in what you've presented, and one clear error.  You say,

> I get a file called `libprocs.la` in procs but I don't get a binary. I
>   am also fairly certain that my Makefiles are wrong since I can't even
>   compile `main.cpp` by hand.

Surely `make`'s output contains one or more error messages that explain why the build fails.  Unless your `make`ing only the `procs` subdirectory in the first place, I guess, in which case *of course* you would not be getting `main` built.

But I'm reasonably confident that I can guess: you're getting a linker error complaining that it can't find `ProcA_SubprocA::ProcA_SubprocA`.  This would be because although your Makefile specifies that the library should be *built* (and also installed), it nowhere says that it needs to be linked into `main`.  There's a pretty easy fix for that, which I will return to in a moment.

First, however, let's talk about `libprocs.la`.  The `.la` suffix is meaningful to the Autotools, designating a "libtool archive", but you're actually building it as an ordinary static library.  Indeed `libtool` isn't doing anything particularly useful for you here; I would dump it by removing the `LT_INIT` from your `configure.ac` (and do not run `libtoolize` again, as it will put that back).  Then, change the name of the library to be built to the more standard `libprocs.a`.

Furthermore, since this library seems to be intended only for use with the one program being built, it is unhelpful to include it in the install in its own right.  Therefore, instead of designating it in `lib_LIBRARIES`, designate it as a non-installed convenience library:

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libprocs.a
```

You will then need to make a corresponding change to the library's `SOURCES` variable:

> ```
> libprocs_la_SOURCES = ...
> ```

```
libprocs_a_SOURCES = ...
```

Coming back to the main program now, you need to tell `make` (and Automake) that the library needs to be linked into program `main`.  There are a few variations on how you could do that, but I'm going to suggest a fairly simple one:

```
main_LDADD = procs/libprocs.a
```

After those changes, rerun `autoreconf` (but not `libtoolize`).  Remember, however, that you need to run that only after changing Autotools sources -- just `Makefile.am` and `configure.ac` files in your case.  It is a detail of maintaining and developing the package and its build system in particular.  It should not be a routine part of building or installing the package.

Comment: I edited the original post according to what I understood you suggested.  Now make throws an error: 
`In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
procs/Subprocs.h:4:28: fatal error: ProcA_SubprocA.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ProcA_SubprocA.h"`
I would have expected my **AM_CPPFLAGS** in *procs/Makefile.am* to take care of this?

Comment: I would have expected that, too, @Lxndr, *unless you are performing a VPATH build*.  In that case, you would need to include `$(srcdir)` in the include path: `-I$(srcdir)/proc1/subprocs/subprocB`.  Personally, though, I don't see why you are relying on compiler flags for this in the first place.  Myself, I would be putting the appropriate paths directly into `Subprocs.h`, instead.  This is one of the oddities I referred to, but I declined to bring it up in the answer so as to focus on the main problem.

Comment: I put the paths directly into the header files and it works now. Thanks!